# How can I disable Automatically managing signing option in jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins

I'm making CI using jenkins and Xcode plugin. But it was failed with log like that

> Check dependencies Unity-iPhone has conflicting provisioning settings.
>   Project is automatically signed, but provisioning profile <>
>   has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to
>   "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing
>   in the project editor. Code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  Check dependencies (1 failure)
>   Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

So I searched solution. And I found some solutions. 
First. Setting Custom xcodebuild argument in Xcode plugin in jenkins. So I made argument like below.

```
    "ProvisioningStyle = Manual"
    "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=<<name>>" 
"DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=<<team>>"
    "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0"
```

But it was failed with same log.

Second. I used Execute shell in jenkins like below

```
sed -i '' 's/ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
/ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
/' Project.xcodeproj/Project.pbxproj
```

Bu it was failed with log like below.

```
[Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/c8/mryr3pj14kv7b2yffxm1b6200000gn/T/hudson7046742057279779985.sh
+ sed -i '' 's/ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
/ProvisioningStyle = Manual;
/' Project.xcodeproj/Project.pbxproj
sed: 1: "s/ProvisioningStyle = A ...": unterminated substitute pattern
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

May I used script worng or there are another solution?. Actually I meat jenkins first and xocde first. Can you explain solution easily and give me details?

Comment: Hi Seunghun, welcome to SO. Please explain what "did not work". See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I solved it. I make xcconfig file and use it when I xcodebuild

Comment: First I manually build first. unity and Xcode build. Second. I copy and backup info.plist and project.pbxproj. Third I copy the files and replace them when I using jenkins. Then Xcode setting is seated manually and profiling and so on.

Comment: I'd upvote this because it resolved our same problem on Jenkins that an ios app auto-build-job always failed while on the Mac host within XCode IDE it can success. Saved our day.