# Xcode build fail in Xcode plugin in jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins

I'm making CI using jenkins, Xcode8.0, unity5.4

I read some information about Xcode plugin.
So I set parameter in xcode plugin

Genral build setting - target : Unity-iPhone
Code signing & OS X keychain opations

New bundle ID : xxx
Code Signing Identity : xxx

Advanced Xcode build option - Custome xcodebuild arguments :
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = xxxxxx

And I build it then build fail with log

> Going to invoke xcodebuild:target: Unity-iPhone, sdk: DEFAULT,
>   project: DEFAULT, configuration: Release, clean: NO, archive:NO,
>   symRoot: DEFAULT, configurationBuildDir:
>   /Users/Project/jenkins/Agent/workspace/CI_Test/build/ios/build/Unity-iPhone.build,
>   codeSignIdentity: iPhone Distribution: Distribution [ios] $
>   /usr/bin/xcodebuild -target Unity-iPhone -configuration Release build
>   CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/user/jenkins/Agent/workspace/test/build/ios/build/Unity-iPhone.build
>   "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Distribution: user."
>   DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = xxxxx 2017-03-31 11:50:45.328
>   xcodebuild[9122:9204847] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in
>   compatibility UUID E0A62D1F-3C18-4D74-BFE5-A4167D643966 for plug-in at
>   path '~/Library/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present
>   in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs 2017-03-31 11:50:45.329
>   xcodebuild[9122:9204847] Failed to load plugin at:
>   /Users/Royalblood/Library/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin, skipping. 
>   Reason for failure: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0] 2017-03-31 11:50:45.943 xcodebuild[9122:9204847] [MT]
>   DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-11754/DVTFoundation/MacroExpansion/DVTMacroDefinitionTable.mm:1254
>   Details:  macroName should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty
>   string Object:    Method:
>   -setObject:forKeyedSubscript: Thread:   {number = 1, name = main} Hints: None Backtrace:   0
>   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in DVTFoundation)   1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)   2
>   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)   3   -[DVTMacroDefinitionTable setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] (in DVTFoundation)   4   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool
>   _resolveInputOptionsWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)   5   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)   6  0x000000010caa6202 (in xcodebuild)   7   start (in libdyld.dylib)
>   Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

I don't know this log what mean and I don't know what I miss. I tried xcodebuild manually using xcodeplugin, but I failed. So I changed my way to xcodebuild automatically using jenkins.

Comment: I solved it. I make xcconfig file and use it when I xcodebuild

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067449/how-can-i-disable-automatically-managing-signing-option-in-jenkins